# Rails Elasticsearch analyzer mappings defined in model are not reported in elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, sense

In my Recipe model I have :

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

index_name "recipes-#{Rails.env}"

settings do
  mappings dynamic: 'false' do
    indexes :title, type: 'string', analyzer: 'french'
    indexes :description, type: 'string', analyzer: 'french'
  end
end

def as_indexed_json(options={})
  self.as_json({only: [:title, :description]})
end
```

Then in rails console, I launch `Recipe.import`. When asking to elasticsearch via curl or Sense `GET /recipes-development/_mapping/`, I get

```
{
   "recipes-development": {
      "mappings": {
         "recipe": {
            "properties": {
               "description": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "title": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have lost all informations about analyzer. Any idea would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `Recipe.import` you have to execute

```
Recipe.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force: true
```